# What do you call bracelets you wear around the legs?

Tags: word-request

[image: a gold wrap-around bracelet]

This is a bracelet, and it's jewelry worn around the arm, but what about jewelry worn around the legs? What do you call it? Is there a particular name for it, or do you just have to call it leg-jewelry?

Comment: My google for `leg bracelet` found the wikipedia entry for Anklet on the first page of results, and it was used in the text of earlier results (mostly shops selling them).  Are you ruling that out because you're asking about leg jewelry that's worn higher up on the leg, like around the calf or knee?

Comment: @PeterCordes that almost sounds like a question of its own... I can't think of a word for "knee jewellery" and "garter" is made of fabric so doesn't fit.

Comment: @Criggie: IDK if knee jewelry exists at all, though, other than athletic knee braces that might possibly have stickers on them.  The piece of jewelry in the picture got me thinking it could maybe be worn around a calf, because it doesn't look like it would work as an anklet (to long, and rigid so it won't bend with the ankle).  It really does look like *arm* jewelry, not wrist jewelry.  Like maybe even *upper* arm, but maybe just floating around on the forearm.

Comment: This is rather unrelated to your actual question, but [in my AmE experience] native speakers rarely refer to a piece of jewelry as a jewel.  It's technically correct, but not very idiomatic.  We tend to reserve "jewel" for the precious stones which are frequently used as decorations in jewelry.

Comment: I'll edit OP's question regarding that , @A C

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There are "anklets", which are worn around the ankles.

From [Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anklet)

> An anklet, also called ankle chain, ankle bracelet or ankle string, is
>   an ornament worn around the ankle.

Note that "ankle bracelet" in some contexts could be misconstrued as an ankle monitoring device used in law enforcement.

Also, please note that "bracelets" are worn around the wrists. It is clear and natural to say someone wore a bracelet on their arm, but most native speakers will take that to mean it is on that person's wrist.  I think the object in your picture would be worn on the upper arm, and therefore is not a bracelet.

There is something called a "bangle". Here is Wikipedia on bangles, for convenience:

["Bangle" on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bangle)

But yes, in some cases you would simply say "jewelry". (I suggest not calling it a "jewel")  Leg-jewelry is little bit odd, so, personally, I would rearrange the phrase to say (He wore) "jewelry on his leg".

Comment: Note that at least in Am.E, "ankle bracelet" can also commonly refer to an [ankle monitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ankle_monitor) which is a tracking device used to monitor the movements of people e.g. under house arrest. If there isn't enough context to clearly indicate that you're talking about personal decoration, someone might think this is what you're referring to.